# Why does my stored procedure with cursor not run OK?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

Bellow is my code define inside store procedure, debug query select have results but debug code SELECT order_id return NULL result and no rows add to table3.
 please help

```
BEGIN
declare done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
declare id int;
declare order_id int;
declare amount DECIMAL;
declare shipping_date datetime;
declare code VARCHAR(20);
declare cur1 cursor for 
select p.*   from (SELECT id,order_id,amount,shipping_date from order_detail od where
od.status in (0)
 and od.shipping_date <DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL -10 DAY))p
join `order` o on o.id =p.order_id  and o.status in (0,11)
and o.country = 'US'   and o.is_dvg = 0 ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
DROP  TABLE IF EXISTS table3;
CREATE   TABLE table3 (id int,order_id int,amount DECIMAL,shipping_date datetime);

SELECT done;
    open cur1;
    igmLoop: loop

        fetch cur1 into id,order_id,amount,shipping_date;
         SELECT order_id;
        if done = 1 then leave igmLoop; end if;

        INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (id,order_id,amount,shipping_date);
     end loop igmLoop;
    close cur1;
 SELECT * from table3;
END
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to have variable names that are the same as table names.

Comment: A decimal field which does not specify the number of decimal places will default to 10,0

Comment: Assuming select p.*   from ... works then so does the procedure.

Comment: Follow the advices of @P.Salmon. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fWSr2SsKoRYH78gsfr2huf/1).